# Why does the finance industry uses 2TDEA instead of 3TDEA?

Tags: cryptography, financial

Why does the finance industry uses 2TDEA instead of 3TDEA?

Is there any historical reason or technical limitations like the support by HSMs used in the industry?

[The paper referred to here](http://crypto.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Estiglic/Papers/tripleDES.pdf) says simply that the financial industry has not considered 3TDEA as it does not offer extra security.

> Triple-DES, noted as 3DES from here on, uses 2 keys, chosen
> independently at random, to DES encrypt a message multiple times.
> There are also ways to use 3DES with 3 different keys, but these
> schemes do not give a significant amount of extra security in theory
> and are not considered in financial systems.

3TDEA is supposed to be very secure (I am not a cryptanalyst, but I want to be one), but why has it not been considered?

I think I am missing something big/fundamental here. Can you please help?

P.S: this is not my homework or anything.

Comment: See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/why-is-triple-des-using-three-different-keys-vulnerable-to-a-meet-in-the-middle why 3TDEA is not more secure than 2TDEA -- but both are secure enough -- and combine with @Griffin "it ain't broke don't fix it". Plus remember bank systems generally risk only money in limited amounts that can be replaced "good as new", unlike really private information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like they do not see a need for it. It seems as if their idea is its not needed so let's not do it. The way they see it. If you are trying to keep people from opening a box and you shoot that box into space on a rocket does it matter if it lands on Mars or Pluto? While yes it's harder to reach Pluto and takes longer nobody on mars is opening your box anyway. Once people are able to reach mars maybe then they'll start thinking about Pluto but that's a bridge they'll cross when they come to it.

IMO: Banks don't like change. Updating takes time and money. More things the bank doesn't like to use. Any changes that doesn't bring profit are usually only done when they have to be. Also I'm not sure if this is the definate reason. If I am off I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Banks, like any large corporate, need to weigh up pros and cons of any decision, as all change costs money. It generally **has** been considered.

As Griffin pointed out, **sufficient** security is all that is needed, with a bit of forward planning to be able to upgrade when it gets close to being needed.

Sometimes increasing technical security via a stronger algorithm or process can actually reduce overall security or impact operations (eg through more helpdesk calls)

Comment: "Sometimes increasing technical security via a stronger algorithm or process can actually reduce overall security "  can you please help me understand ?